# expressions meaning to risk death

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests, synonyms

I am looking for expressions roughly synynymous wtih 'to risk death'. 
The following are some examples. Can you think of others?

*to risk one's life*

*to put one's life on the line*

*to flirt with death*

*to dice with death*

*to mortgage one's life*

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Is something like death wish what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi Apollyon. Please telli us where this expression will be used. And why don't the ones you listed work for you.

Comment: I've never heard "to dice with death", or "to mortgage one's life" before. I **have** heard "to dance with death", on the other hand. Generally, it's a tango...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ***tempt*** death is an alternative expression:

> - To tempt: To provoke or to risk provoking (AHD)

- "Local men to [tempt 'death'](http://poststar.com/news/opinion/columns/ps/local-men-to-tempt-death/article_91a5c084-4d26-11e1-9700-001871e3ce6c.html) :(Poststar.com)

> - Two local men will be competing in a Vermont-based race that bears the slogan, "You may die."

Answer (score 1):

Not a saying or proverb, but you would sound original saying "**to play chess with Thanatos**".

> - In Greek mythology, [Thanatos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanatos) /ˈθænətɒs/ was the daemon personification of death. He was a minor figure in Greek mythology, often referred to, but rarely appearing in person. [image]

*Thanatos as a winged and sword-girt youth. Sculptured marble column drum from the Temple of Artemis at Ephesos*

> - Thanatos -  "Death as a personification or as a philosophical notion." [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Thanatos)

Answer (score 1):

There is always to **[play Russian roulette](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+Russian+roulette)**

> to take big risks, in a way which is very dangerous
>  Usage notes:
> Russian roulette is a very dangerous game where players aim a gun
> containing one bullet at their own heads.
>  (often + with ) *I'm not
> willing to play Russian roulette with people's lives by drinking and
> driving.*

(thefreedictionary.com)

[More info on the origin of the phrase on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_roulette). It claims that

> In writing, the term "Russian Roulette" was first used in an eponymous
> 1937 short story by Georges Surdez:
>
> *'Did you ever hear of Russian Roulette?' ... With the Russian army in
> Romania, around 1917, some officer would suddenly pull out his
> revolver, remove a cartridge from the cylinder, spin the cylinder,
> snap it back in place, put it to his head and pull the trigger."*
>
> It is claimed that this practice was widely known in Russia in
> the early 19th century. However, there is only one written source
> before the 20th century: in Mikhail Lermontov's 1840 "The Fatalist",
> one of five novellas comprising his A Hero of Our Time, a minor
> character survives a version of Russian roulette.

Comment: Interesting. The modern definition has the odds inverted. The 'game' [described by Surdez](https://monlegionnaire.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/russian-roulette-by-georges-surdez/) gives the player very low chances of not shooting himself in the head. He says 16.7%- correct for a six-shooter with all the chambers loaded originally. A seven-chamber [Nagant M1895](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagant_M1895) would give even worse odds.