# Is there an English equivalent for the Persian proverb "to play with the tail of a lion"?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, translation, proverb-requests

The Persian proverb ***to play with the tail of a lion*** is used informally to say that a certain situation is very dangerous. By saying it, we alert the listener that the act which they are about to do is likely to result in their death.

> Example: Driving too rapidly in a busy road is like ***[playing with the tail of a lion.]***

Is there a proverb that would express the same thing in English?

---

I have already heard the expression ***to play with fire***, but it doesn't quite work because the Persian proverb has a bit of a chiding tone- the speaker wants both to alarm and ridicule the listener. The aim is to say that the act is at the same time dangerous and foolish.

Comment: Aren't you the same person who asked about [the cow with the white forehead](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/404693/is-there-any-equivalent-for-this-persian-idiom-like-a-cow-with-a-white-forehea)? You must really like persian proverbs.

Comment: As a matter a fact , I am translating a short story from Persian into English .Therefore I  have to ask many question to find the best equivalent to Persian proverbs that I come across. Besides , Persian is a poetical language in which you can  find many proverbs , metaphors , idioms.

Comment: I didn't say it was a bad thing, it's just unusual to have such similar questions crop up in such a short space of time (And for both to end up on the 'hot network questions' list).

Comment: The questions related to proverbs and expressions are always popular , for this reason I have decided to ask only such questions :) ha!ha!ha

Comment: Are you wanting to keep the proverbs as close to the original (in both meaning and flavor)?  "Grab the lion by the tail" would probably get the meaning across with minimal change to the text.

Comment: I don't know how important it is to arrive at a *commonly used* English phrase. If all you really need is to convey the meaning and the "feel" to a native English speaker, then the direct (naive) translation of the Persian phrase is already suitable.

Comment: @JOHN So , do you think that the native  reader understand the story behind that at  the first glance?

Comment: @kazhvan - Absolutely.

Comment: Just as an anecdotal curiosity: in certain countries you say _pulling the lion's [whiskers](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whiskers)_.

Comment: You have receive many good answers. But any metaphor indicating eminent danger would work. One possibility: *BASE jumping without a chute*.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson I don’t think that would work so well. It’s too similar to “grab/take the bull by the horns”, which has an entirely different meaning. The grabbing bit makes it _intentional_ and _confrontational_, like you’re not only playing with fire, but knowingly doing something you know is dangerous, but in a way that makes it look like you know what you’re doing and you’re facing the danger head-on. Playing with a lion’s tail feels like quite a different thing to me.

Comment: Dear Kahzvan: which proverb has the humorous connotation - the Persian or the "Playing with Fire" one? "Playing with fire", although thoroughly beclichéed, is usually meant very earnestly and not meant to make fun of the player: it usually also implies the player is threatened by side effects that they may not have thought of or are foolhardishly ignoring - "watch out" is the undertext that goes with it.

Comment: Note that the almost identical sounding  ["to have a tiger by the tail"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+tiger+by+the+tail) in English means something related but distinct, that what you think you have control over is actually rather volatile. Sure it could easily be dangerous but the emphasis is on out of control.

Comment: The meaning of the direct translation is immediately evident and in my opinion better than anything English has to offer.

Answer (score 78):

***Playing with fire*** is similar. However, it implies only that the activity is highly dangerous (or foolish), but not necessary lethal.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/play_with_fire

There is also ***sailing close to the wind*** - which means taking unnecessary risks. I'd guess this is also less serious than the OP's example.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sail-close-to-the-wind

If someone is really endangering their life, we'd say they're ***dicing with death***

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dice_with_death

Comment: +1. Here's a [dictionary entry](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/play_with_fire) you can use in your answer to provide some independent support for your answer.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot 'skating on thin ice' ... which is also in the 'stupid, but not Darwin Awards stupid' category

Comment: I would say "playing with matches" is a variant of this, which carries the connotation of someone doing something more dangerous than he appreciates (which makes the situation effectively more dangerous than if he understood the dangers and was carefully trying to avoid them).

Comment: "Sailing close to the wind" tends to have an additional connotation of a calculated risk for expediency's sake - when you are actually sailing "close to the wind" you are travelling faster.

Comment: @caf On an actual sailboat, the fastest speed is in a downwind direction (not quite a dead run); for any other point of sail, the closer to the wind you sail the slower your speed. Of course the _direction_ of travel also changes as the boat's heading changes, which is where the advantages (and risks) of sailing close to the wind come into play.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/255563/expressions-meaning-to-risk-death

Comment: "dicing with death"? I never heard that one, though I have heard "flirting with death".

Comment: @DavidK No, most modern boats are faster on a beam reach than straight downwind: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/186515/why-is-a-beam-reach-the-fastest-point-of-sail-on-modern-sailboats

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Multiple answers on the page you linked made the same point I was trying to make: the fastest point of sail of a monohull sailboat in a strong wind is _not_ close to the wind at all; it is a broad reach--as I said, _not_ a dead run, but in _a_ downwind direction. Apparently the beam reach is fastest for a catamaran, which is news to me, but that's still hardly what most sailors would call close to the wind.

Comment: @DavidZ"dicing with death" == gambling with death. Well known phrase in Australian English, alliteration for the win. Google ngrams has it about equal to flirting with death.

Comment: Sailing close to the wind is risky if you are a sail-driven warship; too close to the wind, and you come to halt, bad news if someone is chasing you. So the risk is not going too fast, the opposite: losing all speed. Off to the library for you, to find Master & Commander. Twenty books later, you'll know all about sailing close to the wind :)

Comment: I've heard "dance with death" on rare occasion (US English, though I think I got it from books)

Comment: Another aspect of "sailing close to the wind", is that in actual practice the sailors 'feel' like they're making great progress because of the higher apparent wind coming at them and pitching into wavefronts faster ... when in fact there can be little speed over ground. So it can be a bit foolish, apart form the risk of ending up 'in irons' (Although I'm sure that's not the origin of the term... @TR's naval explanation makes perfect sense)

Answer (score 66):

Don't poke the bear / Poking the bear

> Urban Dictionary : A phrase of warning used to prevent oneself or others from asking or doing something that might provoke a negative response from someone or something else.

Comment: Thank you . it is the first time that I hear this expression .

Comment: @kazhvan no problem, I'm surprised you haven't heard it before, it's a very common english expression

Comment: @kazhvan I'm native English (i.e. from England) and have never heard this before either. I think this might be an American saying (we don't get many bears in Britain).

Comment: I'm a native American English speaker, and I'm actually not familiar with this phrase either. Maybe it's regional. But even though I have never heard it before, the meaning is clear. The same can be said of "playing with the lion's tail". There is more than enough information embedded in each word that additional explanation is not necessary.

Comment: "Poking the bear" can also have the political meaning of provoking Russia.

Comment: This was definitely common in the midwest, where I grew up.

Comment: (Just because we're all adding data points here...) Grew up in the PNW and totally familiar with this phrase.

Comment: I'm from the northeast U.S., and I'm familiar with this expression (but I'm a bookworm, so that may not prove much). To me it connotes finding a hibernating bear in a cave, and poking it with a stick. I don't actually know how dangerous that is, but I am content in my ignorance.

Comment: Another PNW ("Pacific Northwest" - Oregon & Washington) native who grew up with this phrase.  I also always imagined that the bear is hibernating.  He sleeps and sleep, so it seems safe to pester him.  Then one time you poke him too hard and wake him up.  He has a nice little snack and goes back to bed with you in his belly.

Comment: This was the first phrase I thought of, but I'm from Pennsylvania, which is basically midwest.

Comment: Oddly enough, I don't recall ever hearing this phrase used (New Zealand) but I *have* used it myself.  I guess it's just a very obvious construction.

Comment: KY here, common phrase.

Comment: Can’t think of any time I’ve heard it (mostly Northeast US, some time in California), but it’s perfectly understandable.

Comment: Note the bear is usually related to a specific person/group/nation, so would not fit the example well (driving too fast).  The common useage is meant to say don't annoy/prod someone into causing you problems.

Comment: Another alternative to this is a 'hornets nest'. E.g. poking, kicking, stirring up the hornet's nest, which will get you stung by an angry swarm.

Answer (score 47):

I honestly think that **playing with a lion's tail** is perfectly acceptable. Colorful, descriptive English is rife with fun similes like that.

**Skating on thin ice** is like what you are looking for, but I think it misses the absurdity of playing with the lion's tail and replaces it with complacent obliviousness to one's predicament. For a similar reason, I think that **playing with fire** is also a little off, in that it connotes ignorant defiance of danger rather than bravado.

A more mundane, but commonly used phrase is **taking one's life into their own hands.** It generally means that someone will put his/herself into a dangerous situation where their own actions or skill are the only thing that will allow them to escape unscathed. I think this fits your example fairly well - **Driving too rapidly on a busy road is like taking your life into your own hands.**

Comment: "Tweak the lion's tail" is a recognized idiom in English.

Comment: "Tweak the lion's tail" is *not* a recognized idiom in English. (Let's see which comment gets more upvotes. ;))

Comment: "Skating on thin ice" brings to mind very serious situations, with no humour involved, and doesn't necessarily fit all dangerous situations. For example, if someone liked to do parkour on a rooftop, you wouldn't use that phrase; "taking one's life into one's own hands" would be more appropriate. However if a boss wanted to warn one of his employees that he was dangerously close to being fired, the boss might say, "You're skating on very thin ice here mate, I'd be careful about what I say if I were you." I think this is what you were saying already, @TBear, but I wanted to emphasize this :)

Comment: @ExUmbris, "twist the lion's tail" specifically meant to provoke the British

Comment: I'm not sure about the typical Persian climate, but I imagine there's not much ice to speak of. So "skating on thin ice", while otherwise a perfectly valid answer, might not be that suitable in this particular context.

Comment: @ZeroOne It can get to minus 22 F in [Hamadan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamadan).  (minus 30 C)

Comment: @ab2 Oh, wow. I stand corrected then, thank you! But still, do they go skating when it's freezing??

Comment: @ZeroOne I don't know!  I live in Virginia and have never been to Iran.

Comment: @Quuxplusone If some people vote up "recognize" then it *is* recognized by them. The existence of recognition is not a matter of getting the most votes; either it gets some votes or it doesn't. It looks like it's recognized enough that the claim is upheld (it might be regional, for example -- better known in some places that others).

Comment: @Glen_b The fact that the comment was written at all entails that it’s a recognised idiom in English, by the commenter. I think we can safely assume that “recognised” here means “_commonly_ recognised”, though. Googling it, I get only about 30 hits for “tweaking the lion’s tail”, while I get more than 5,000 for “twisting the lion’s tail”. [This Ngram](http://bit.ly/2fCr5ej) shows that, while the ‘tweak’ version had a slight peak around WWII (cf. Separatrix’ comment), the ‘twist’ version has always been far more common.

Comment: @Janus Yes; my intent was "recognized by more than one person"

Answer (score 34):

***tickling the dragon's tail***; [Wikipedia, Louis Slotin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Slotin).

Louis Slotin was a physicist on the Manhattan Project who died in 1946 nine days after his screwdriver slipped in the course of a criticality experiment.

> Criticality testing involved bringing masses of fissile materials to
>   near-critical levels to establish their critical mass values.
>   Scientists referred to this flirting with the possibility of a nuclear
>   chain reaction as "tickling the dragon's tail", based on a remark by
>   physicist Richard Feynman, who compared the experiments to "tickling
>   the tail of a sleeping dragon".

This phrase may be familiar only to physicists and nuclear engineers, but to them the picture of assembling by hand the elements of of a nuclear critical mass, and stopping just short of criticality, is the ultimate game of chicken.

See also Physics Stack Exchange, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/148569/why-did-tickling-the-dragons-tail-by-louis-slotin-not-cause-an-explosion, *Why did “tickling the dragons tail” by Louis Slotin not cause an explosion?*

Comment: Very interesting! However, I don't think it's commonly used by the general public.

Comment: On the other hand it is very close and stands a decent chance of being understood once looked up.

Comment: @Joshua - You don't have to look it up to understand it. Just about any English speaker will know what a dragon is, and will immediately recognize that it's not a good idea to tickle its tail. Of course, the same can be said of playing with a lion's tail.

Comment: Pulling or tickling the [Insert dangerous creature]'s tail is widely recognized. The specific creature varies from place to place.

Comment: I have never heard this expression before, so I can't see how it is any better than the original *playing with a lion's tail.* Sure, you may understand it, but it is still unfamiliar. If this is idiomatic, it appears to refer specifically to the dangers of atomic energy.

Comment: this is a phrase used once by Someone.  the answer has no connection to "figures of speech in English"

Comment: JK Rowling (a British author) used this Latin motto for the school appearing in her Harry Potter series, Hogwarts: _Draco dormiens numquam titillandus_ (“A sleeping dragon should never be tickled.”)

Comment: @chirlu Thanks for this info!  May I add this as a footnote, crediting you?  See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10658/whats-the-point-of-the-hogwarts-motto, the transcript of a interview which explains how she came up with the motto.

Comment: @ab2: Absolutely, feel free to use it.

Comment: This is an excellent example: I was going to given it myself. FYI (if you're not already aware of it): ts full meaning in context implies a few things that are further to and a little different from the OP's phrase. Firstly, it was not meant as a deterring warning: its originator Richard Feynman and his colleagues felt very much that the scientists had to find a way forward whatever the danger. Secondly, he was referring to a specific experiment, and emphasizing that the experiment should only "tickle" yet not "wake" the dragon. The scientists had to check whether there were indeed a dragon ..

Comment: ... there and they needed some "vital statistics" of his living being to confirm their theoretically calculated neutron capture cross sections. It should also be emphasized that at no time was there any danger of an explosion, as I explain in the answer to the Physics SE question you linked. The experiment referred to involved dropping a subcritical uranium slug through a hole in a uranium disk, such that the falling block would fleetingly become critical allowing measurement by nearby instruments. So the experiment would (1) automatically shut itself off and (2) is simple enough for remote ..

Comment: ... control: criticality leads to a lethal pulse of neutrons, and there was always the chance that the slug might swiftly melt and fuse itself to the ring, leading to a sustained criticality - relaxation cycle described in my answer - or more likely the whole lot would melt and end up as a spread out, subcritical but nightmarish pool on the floor. I don't know what would have happenned would the latter have come to pass: I suspect that the lab in question might have to be indefinitely isolated. These days you would send in a sacrificial robot to clean up - the amount of waste would be ...

Comment: ... very small compared to the power station disasters that have happenned since.

Comment: There's a PBS documentary titled ["Uranium - Twisting the Dragon's Tail"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium_%E2%80%93_Twisting_the_Dragon%27s_Tail)

Answer (score 22):

Dancing with the devil.

My father was a policeman who used this expression all the time to describe the behavior of some of his "clients". Particularly the ones who almost got themselves killed doing stupid things.

Comment: Not bad . but not generally accepted

Comment: @kazhvan Do you mean it's not commonly used? Because it's widely used in my experience.

Comment: @kazhvan have heard this more frequently in the southern and midwest US. May not be as well known on the coasts but still conjures the right image.

Answer (score 20):

The most simple expression I know of for this is to [**tempt fate**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tempt-fate-providence)

> If you tempt fate or providence by doing something, you take a silly risk by doing it and depend too much on your good luck:

*Cambridge Dictionary*

So, as per your example:

> Driving too rapidly in a busy road is tempting fate

Answer (score 19):

I like the other answers here, but the playful connotation in the OP makes the question a bit tricky. I'll submit **flirting with disaster** as another option.

It still emphasizes the danger much moreso than the playfulness, but flirting is a pretty light and casual activity. It's also a more modern and less formal version of **courting disaster**, which makes it feel a little less focused on the danger (to me).

---

EDIT: Responding to a request for references, I looked up the phrases on Google's NGram viewer and found my assertion that "flirting with disaster" is more modern was pretty undercut! At least with regard to books published in English between 1800 and 2008 or so.

[NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=courting%20disaster%2Cflirting%20with%20disaster&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2001&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ccourting%20disaster%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcourting%20disaster%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCourting%20Disaster%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCOURTING%20DISASTER%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cflirting%20with%20disaster%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bflirting%20with%20disaster%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFlirting%20with%20Disaster%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFlirting%20With%20Disaster%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFLIRTING%20WITH%20DISASTER%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFlirting%20with%20disaster%3B%2Cc0)

I still say that *flirting with disaster* is more common in speech, if nothing else, if only because *flirting* is in common modern use and *courting* is much less common. I also think that the Molly Hatchet song, *Flirting with Disaster* (released 1979) has probably been driving a lot of my familiarity with the phrase.

Comment: Can you [edit] to show your references?  Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

To [fly too close to the sun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fly_too_close_to_the_sun), in reference to the [Greek myth of Icarus](http://www.mythweb.com/encyc/entries/icarus.html) is another option. It has more of a humorous connotation of foolishness than to play with fire. However, it can also connote ambitiousness or greediness which may not be appropriate.

Comment: AFAIK, "flying too close to the sun" usually implies the person doing it is too proud, rather than foolish. The myth of Icarus is generally interpreted as a warning against hubris.

Answer (score 10):

An idiomatic expression which mirrors the lion metaphor and comes close is: ***ride a tiger***

TFD(idioms):

> **[ride a tiger](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ride+a+tiger)**
>
> To find yourself in a precarious situation.
>   The phrase comes from
>   “He who rides a tiger is afraid to dismount.” Which is to say, once
>   you find yourself in a dangerous circumstance, getting out of it can
>   be even more potentially hazardous, whether to your health or your
>   career.
>
> Endangered Phrases by Steven D. Price Copyright © 2011 by Steven D.
>   Price

Comment: Also: "to have a tiger by the tail", which I think is a more modern version.

Comment: I used to put a tiger in my tank, but then Esso got engulfed by ExxonMobil. Nice tails they had too: https://www.google.com/search?q=esso+tiger+tail&num=20&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwia4b3v58rVAhUL3YMKHfe9Cz0Q_AUICygC&biw=1122&bih=619

Comment: I haven't heard of this but would understand it based on context.

Comment: "Riding a tiger" has the additional implication of "how do you plan to stop?", which the Persian expression doesn't have.

Comment: I've heard tiger-related expressions (perhaps something like "poking a sleeping tiger") used metaphorically when extracting rocks from the bottom of a huge pile (in cave exploration).  For some reason, the expression with a tiger feels less "foreign" than the same expression with a lion - I wonder if this is due to the large Indian influence on English compared to the much smaller influence from Africa?

Answer (score 7):

There's a very similar phrase, ["to beard the lion"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/beard-the-lion) (sometimes expanded with "in his den")

> Confront a danger, take a risk, as in *I went straight to my boss, bearding the lion*

Comment: I would love to understand the downvote. I don't post on here often, but when I saw it on HNQs, I visited, and was *surprised* that there was no reference to bearding the lion. If there had been an existing (more thorough) answer using that phrase I would have instead voted for it. As it was, I saw an unexpected (for me) absence so provided a minimal answer myself.

Answer (score 6):

"Mess with the bull you get the horns." At no point are you in control, of either bull or lion. There are numerous humorous uses of it in popular culture ("The Breakfast Club", "The Pacifier"). [Quora had a good write-up for it](https://www.quora.com/Where-did-the-phrase-If-you-mess-with-the-bull-you-get-the-horns-originate)

Comment: This is a good expression to use, but could you add the definition here, rather than linking to Quora? We want to create answers that are complete in themselves, as stated in the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Also: "mess with the cat, you get the claws." Also: "play stupid games, win stupid prizes." All of these are more like what you'd say *after* the horns/claws have been got or the stupid prize has been won, though.

Comment: A variation on this is "seizing the bull by the horns"... the implication being that bulls (and lions and busy traffic) can be managed but that the person is going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 5):

Jim Croce said it best in "You Don't Mess Around with Jim":

> You don't tug on superman's cape
>
> You don't spit into the wind
>
> You don't pull the mask off that old lone ranger
>
> And you don't mess around with Jim

It must be said that I've heard "don't piss into the wind" at least as often as "don't spit into the wind," which presumably was sanitized for radio.

Comment: Great answer. I had just thought of the 'superman's cape' line.

Answer (score 4):

Catch a 'tiger by the tail'.  (Something too difficult to manage or cope with. Dictionary.com)

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer. To catch a tiger by a tail is to be in an untenable situation. You have the tiger, and you're safe as long as you can hold it. But you will soon tire and have to let it go, at which point it will attack you. You're completely trapped. Whereas with tickling the lion, you could stop tickling and perchance walk away unharmed.

Comment: Upvoted both answer and @user1359's comment - this answer is indeed "wrong", but since it's the most obvious naïve translation, it still needs to be listed here, along with the explanation why it's incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

**Dicing with death** seems to convey the meaning you want.  I have found no definitive derivations but [this discussion](http://www.theanswerbank.co.uk/Phrases-and-Sayings/Question80650.html) suggests that it was only written down in the 1940s although the idea of gaming against death is much older.

Answer (score 2):

to court trouble or courting trouble

Using court as seeming to be asking for circumstances fraught with danger.

Comment: Great suggestion - could you provide some references to show why this is a good answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Dancing with the Devil (in the pale moonlight).

Belling the cat. (Though used mostly with things left undone.)

Playing with dynamite.

Jousting with edged tools. (Or playing with edged tools.)

Answer (score 1):

Late addition to the list, but another idiom that may be relevant to the context is:

[**Belling the cat**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bell+the+cat)

> To undertake or agree to perform a risky, dangerous, or impossible job or task. It comes from a fable (often and likely incorrectly attributed to Aesop) called "Belling the Cat," in which a group of mice decide that one will harness a bell to a murderous cat so that its jingle will warn them of its presence, though none want to take on the dangerous role.

Answer (score 1):

I believe "poke a tiger with a short stick" comes closest in both meaning and spirit.

On a somewhat related note, it's pretty sad there used to be both tigers and lions in Iran until fairly recently, but both species are now gone.

Comment: yes , my friend . this is because politics of Islamic system.

Answer (score 0):

More idiomatic than proverbial, but the person has a [death wish](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=death%20wish)

Answer (score 0):

**Cruising for a bruising**

*slang*

> Acting in a way that is likely to result in punishment or harm. Often shortened colloquially as *"cruisin' for a bruisin'."*

*Oh, you're cruising for a bruising if you keep talking to me like that!*

*Did you hear the way he insulted the boss during our meeting? He's really cruisin' for a bruisin'.*

[The Free Dictionary]

Answer (score 0):

There already is a very similar idiom, although a fairly rare one:

> twisting the lion's tail.

The definition from [*Collins Dictionary*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/twist-the-lions-tail)

> *(American English)*
> to tax the patience of or provoke a person, group, nation, or government, esp. that of Great Britain.

And of course, the *lion* was chosen as the animal because it is the symbol of the United Kingdom.

Answer (score -5):

Poking a sleeping dragon in the eye

Playing with fire

Poke the bear

All can mean the same thing ultimatley

Comment: All of these have been given previously, with actual reference.